# How to get RSS for Impractical Jokers channel in YouTube?

Tags: youtube, rss, feed, youtube-channels

I have tried:

a) [Uploads](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/impracticalJokers/uploads) and it says "This channel is not public.";

b) [Feeds](http://www.youtube.com/rss/user/impracticalJokers/feed.rss) but thats just an empty list.

There is the channel: [Link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCabCeNXfFKoCmPlb4sQ8XEA)

Answer (score 0):

Just add /videos to the end of the channel

[Link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCabCeNXfFKoCmPlb4sQ8XEA/videos)

Now if you drop that link into an rss reader, the feed will generate